# remove multiple files using find and rm in perl

Tags: perl, unix

I have a few text files in my directory which need to be removed. There are a bunch of text files in my directory:

```
leaves_emp1.txt
pay_emp1.txt
pf_emp1.txt
leaves_emp2.txt
pay_emp2.txt
pf_emp2.txt

[...]
```

I've tried using the following code to remove the files containing "emp1":

```
/usr/bin/find $LogDir -name \"leaves_emp1.txt\" -and -name \"pay_emp1.txt\" -and -name \"pf_emp1.txt\" -exec rm {}
```

But it is not working. Please help. I tried with -a and -o too. I also tried using the () for the files.

Comment: I've re-tagged with perl, as you clearly want to run this within a perl script - yes?

Comment: Yes. But I have found a way to do it. I am just using -name \"*emp1.txt\". Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing -and and -or.

Answer (score 0):

I am just using the code as follows

```
/usr/bin/find $LogDir -name \"*emp1.txt\" -exec rm {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid fork-bombs.  The "exec" call in find will spawn a fork/exec with each file.  I find it much easier and scalable to call something like this:

```
    find . -type f -name '*emp1.txt' | perl -lane 'unlink $_ if -f $_' -
```

Note: if you want to stick with just exec, you must remember to use the "\;" at the end

```
    find . -type f -name '*emp1.txt' -exec rm {} \;
```